# Redirect more than one domain links to another domain link

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have four links which I want to redirect to four another domain link. This is the link :

```
1. https://example.com/book.php?bid=U0FOMDAwNzQ%2C&&dcode=ADVVV
2. https://example.com/book.php?bid=U0FOMDAwNzQ%2C&&dcode=BNMAF
3. https://example.com/book.php?bid=U0FOMDAwNzQ%2C&&dcode=DFTTW
4. https://example.com/book.php?bid=U0FOMDAwNzQ%2C&&dcode=DRETT
```

I want redirect that links to :

```
1. https://example2.com/book/ADVVV
2. https://example2.com/book/BNMAF
3. https://example2.com/book/DFTTW
4. https://example2.com/book/DRETT
```

How to I redirect all that links ? With `.htaccess` or anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess` code to redirect given links :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/book.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bid=U0FOMDAwNzQ%2C&&dcode=([A-Z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com/book/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]

</IfModule>
```